# iTextPdf setEncryption with no permission

Tags: java, encryption, permissions, itext

I am encrypting a pdf with a password like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("zrsz.pdf"));
    writer.setEncryption("ownerPass".getBytes(), "userPass".getBytes(), PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING, PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128);
        writer.createXmpMetadata();
        document.open();
        document.add(new Paragraph("This is create PDF with Password demo."));
    document.close();
    System.out.println("Done");
   }
```

but I couldn't find a way to give a "No permission" parameter to this `setEncryption` method :

```
public void setEncryption(byte[] userPassword,
                          byte[] ownerPassword,
                          int permissions,
                          int encryptionType)
```

Is it even possible ? I want to restrict access to that file to minimum. I am just using it to read confidential data.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Have you tried 0 as value of `permissions`?

Comment: Yes, but the pdf reader allow changes once the pdf document is opened with any correct password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the manual you can use all the following as the [Docs](https://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/latest/) said

> Sets the encryption options for this document. The userPassword and
>   the ownerPassword can be null or have zero length. In this case the
>   ownerPassword is replaced by a random string. The open permissions for
>   the document can be AllowPrinting, AllowModifyContents, AllowCopy,
>   AllowModifyAnnotations, AllowFillIn, AllowScreenReaders, AllowAssembly
>   and AllowDegradedPrinting

All the above operations permitted when the document is opened with the user password. So you have a security measure that only users who enter valid credentials(password) can manipulate it.

Comment: hehehe, your answer made me realize that changes done in the pdf reader (I use Adobe Acrobat Reader) are kept. In fact, permissions won't really change a thing once the password is correct. I will have to enforce a very good password then. Thank you for your help !